# Microsoft Word - How to find and title capitalize a string between located between two other strings?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, find-and-replace

I have a reference bib file with several hundred repetitive entries with the following syntax:

```
@article{author2020article,
  title={This is Some Random Article Title},
  author={Author, Name1 and Author, Name2 and Author, Name3 and Author, Name4},
  journal={This is a journal name here},
  volume={1},
  number={5},
  pages={447--455},
  year={2020},
  publisher={This is Some Publisher}
}
```

I would like to properly capitalize journal names, i.e from: `This is a journal name here`, to: `This is a Journal Name Here`.

I'm struggling with Microsoft Word's implementation of regular expression. So far I got to being able to select the whole journal entry line using:

```
journal\=\{*?\},
```

but I'm stuck when I need to do something with it.

I would like to:

1. Find the all instances of journal titles (that is, the title alone, between the curly brackets, and not the whole line)
2. Exclude certain words, if possible (e.g. "is", "a", "an", "the", etc.)
3. Change the capitalization

What I've been doing so far was to find all occurrences using the Find dialog and the wildcard search shown above, change the case to Capitalize Each Word using the UI menus, and then manually revert capitalization for some of the words (`Journal` to `journal`, `Is` to `is`, etc.)

Is there a way to do this via Find and Replace dialog? At least for some of the three steps.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Is it mandatory to modify the file with MS Word?

Comment: Hi Reddy and thank you. No, not really. I would like to avoid VBA but if I could pull off regular Regular Expressions that would work too. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: I gave you an answer at stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62966549/372239 , please don't cross post.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know this is a cross-post as my understanding is that Office uses different implementation of regular expression. I was trying to ask in both communities to see if any would have a solution.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is cross posted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62966549/372239) as per [this Meta topic](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5973/911683).